# Why some app not responding after update Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu-20.04

After update Ubuntu 20.04 some app like: terminal, thunderbird, sublime text, software updater are not opeing or opening very slow and a message "APPNAME is not responding" with two option "Force quit" or "Wait" is displayed. Other applications like chrome, rubymine ar working correctly

How can i fix this issue?
Thank you

Comment: Get Software Updater working and get your system updated. You may need to log into Software Updater but it works in V20.04 and also in V22.04 that I am using now.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Go to System Monitor. Go to the Resources tab. What is the percentage of memory used? What is the percentage of Swap memory used? On my laptop, it is 80% and 30% respectively. The CPU usage is on average 40%. Hence, the problem is with RAM. The processor is not slow. Thus, I can upgrade my RAM. See if this information helps you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).